# Does this jQuery use Server Resources?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, master-pages

My question is related to master pages and id tags.  If we have a html control called **tbxName** on a separate file and we embed it into a master page, it becomes **MasterPage_tbxName**.

So I know of two ways to refer to this item . . .

the straight-forward name method

```
$('#MasterPage_tbxName')
```

and the safer, block-code method

```
$('#<%=tbxName.ClientID%>')
```

Does the safer, block-code method, impose a resource tax every time the page is generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'ends with' jQuery ID selector eg...

```
$('[ID$="_tbxName"]')
```

which I imagine is not very efficient but will still take, oooh a good 2ms.

But if that's an issue then you would just cache that control in your JS file eg...

```
var $tbxName = $('[ID$="_tbxName"]');
```

and then simply refer to `$tbxName`, and then the jQuery selector will not need to be executed again.

Also, the fact that you propose doing `$('#<%=tbxName.ClientID%>')` suggests that your JS is actually in your .aspx file - I would advise putting your JS into separate .js files and referencing with `<script>` tags in the .aspx.

Comment: you know . . 2ms will ad up fairly quickly

Comment: i didn't write any javascript code in the page. im literally learning this straight out of the book. as you can tell, im very new to jquery and asp.net. lol

Comment: No probs :) But in terms of how much resource either method would use, I really wouldn't worry about that at this stage. It's very minimal and unless you're serving the page up 1000s of times a second or jQuery-selecting the control 1000s of times a second I would concentrate on other stuff!

Answer (score 2):

It does take some time for parser to parse your <%=tbxName.ClientID%> tag, but that's matter of nanoseconds, and shouldn't concern you too much. I mean, it's something that server-side web languages are built for, it's one of their narrow purposes.

Regards.